# Why does sstatic.net serve cookies?

Tags: support, cdn, cookies, performance

According to [sstatic.net](https://sstatic.net/):

> This is a fast, cookieless domain intended for static content
> delivered to the [Stack Exchange family of websites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

However, all responses from the server set a cookie anyway:

```
$ http https://sstatic.net/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CF-RAY: 162b88245bc406be-LHR
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 31 Aug 2014 19:11:04 GMT
ETag: W/"d5474fdfb5c3cf1:0"
Last-Modified: Fri, 29 Aug 2014 18:20:12 GMT
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db60cc6f3e7f6482e37f1f2b85c9dc5881409512264375; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.sstatic.net; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
[...]
```

Is this intentional, or just funny?

*Edited to add:* I understand that the cookie is used to track visiting browsers so that cloudflare can distinguish them from misbehaving hosts using the same or a nearby IP address. However, if the policy is intentionally to serve cookies, then the self-documentation of sstatic.net as a "cookieless domain" is incorrect.

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170156-What-does-the-CloudFlare-cfduid-cookie-do-

Comment: Does the fact that CloudFlare always "pollutes" component requests with a cookie negate the usefulness of sstatic.net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sstatic.net is getting cookies even though it says cookieless](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247406/sstatic-net-is-getting-cookies-even-though-it-says-cookieless)

Comment: @Braiam This question is the earlier one.

Comment: Age doesn't matter. The other has an answer.