# sstatic.net is getting cookies even though it says cookieless

Tags: bug, cookies

https://cdn.sstatic.net/ says it is a cookieless domain, but according to muMatrix sstatic.net is requesting 2 cookies

Comment: Sorry, what is muMatrix? (Google seems to know nothing of this name that would be a software.) I had one cookie from sstatic.net (maybe quite old), deleting it doesn't seem to change anything and it wasn't re-created.

Comment: @yo' Probably [μMatrix](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix).

Comment: @senshin Ah ok, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The short of it: I get one cookie from Cloudflare, used to track you as a legitimate user, and Cloudflare wasn't in use when that page was created/no one's bothered to update it.

Now, in story form:

Once upon a time, before [the land was awash with riches](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/?cb=1) and [the harvest was bountiful](http://www.businessinsider.com.au/chefs-at-stack-exchange-2014-2), Stack Exchange was a simpler place, a smaller place. In this land of old there came to be a wee server, Sir Sstatic, who dutifully served up static resources without complaint or cookies.

But this was not to last. The network was growing, and the visitors from far away lands needed a reprieve from the long journey to and from the kingdom of Stack Exchange. Thus [a CDN was introduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90073/help-us-test-the-advantages-of-using-a-cdn) to shoulder the burden that Sir Sstatic had carried for many years, and the travellers rejoiced.

Not all was well, though. The network continued to grow and attract attention, and the masters of the land knew proactive steps must be taken to counteract what was [an inevitable threat](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/433564616518815744). And so the Knights of [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) were brought in, as their reputation for defeating the unrelenting hordes was widely known. Part of their mission of peace involved providing good-intentioned visitors with [tokens of safety*](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170156-What-does-the-CloudFlare-cfduid-cookie-do-), so that they might avoid being swept up accidentally in an offensive.

Though many things had changed, the legacy of Sir Sstatic lived on in legend. And since the lords and ladies of the kingdom had [moved on to other matters of governance](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/557709308704874496), no scribes were assigned to reflect the changing reality of the times. Such is life, I'm afraid.

<sub>*While these tokens are rumoured to smell like delicious baked goods, consuming them is not recommended</sub>